# add div container after each header using DOMParser

Tags: javascript, domparser

with a string of

```
<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>
```

I'm trying to insert a div container after the `header`, with the text of the `header` as its `id` and the content (everything before the next header) after the header so that it becomes

```
<h1>aa</h1><div id="aa"><p>xx</p><p>yy</p></div><h1>aaa</h1><div id="aaa"><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p></div>
```

so far this is what I've made

```js
let s = "<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*');

[...elems].forEach(el => {
  if (el.textContent !== '' && el.tagName === 'H1') {    
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id='${el.textContent}' />`)
    // 
  }
});
  
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Is there an easier way of doing this such as something to add an opening div after the header and a closing div before the next header? there just isn't much examples of this I could find and Google has more examples of xml, php or java uses of `DOMParser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DIV` on the fly using [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and move `<P>` element using [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
let s = "<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*');

[...elems].forEach(el => {
  if (el.textContent !== '' && el.matches('H1')) {
    // create div container
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    //Set Id 
    div.id = el.textContent;

    // Get the next sibling next until H1
    var siblings = nextUntil(el, 'H1');
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
      // move sibling into div
      div.appendChild(siblings[i]);
    }

    // insert div before el in the DOM tree
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
  }
});

function nextUntil(elem, selector) {
  // Setup siblings array
  var siblings = [];
  // Get the next sibling element
  elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // As long as a sibling exists
  while (elem) {
    // If we've reached our match
    if (elem.matches(selector))
      break;

    // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
    siblings.push(elem);

    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
}

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```